# How make this function html_safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm writing helper to render html table header

```
def display_standard_table(columns)
  content_tag :table do
    content_tag :thead do
      content_tag :tr do
        concat columns.collect { |column| content_tag(:th, 'Header'.html_safe) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The html output is escaped:

```
<table><thead><tr>&lt;th&gt;Header&lt;/th&gt;&lt;th&gt;Header&lt;/th&gt;</tr></thead></table>
```

How do I make it unescaped?

[SOLUTION]

```
def display_standard_table(columns, objects = [])
  content_tag :table do
    content_tag :thead do
      content_tag :tr do
        columns.collect { |column| content_tag(:th, column[:display_name]) }.join()
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`concat`? use `join` on the mapped array and see what happens.

Comment: thank's join solved the issue. But i still can't understand why concat mess up things. Can you clearify it to me?

Comment: In short: no. I never ever used `concat`. ;-)